# What is the use-case for `CancellationTokenSource.TryReset`?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource

`CancellationTokenSource` has a `TryReset()` member.  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.tryreset?view=net-6.0) appears so strict as to make me wonder why it exists.

- It will only work if no-one has already called `Cancel()` on it.
- It is only valid to use when any previous asynchronous operations issued with its token have completed, which means (I think) that I would need to hang on to my Task object to track whether it is still running
- It is not safe to call when someone else is trying to cancel the operation, requiring

So why would people bother with `TryReset`?  Why not simply create a brand new `CancellationTokenSource` for every asynchronous operation and then throw it away after the operation completes and cancellation is no longer needed?  Is `CancellationTokenSource` a terribly expensive object to create?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Here you can find the [original issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48492)
- Here you can find the [related pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/50346)

Let me quote here the **Background and Motivation** section of the issue

> When a library or framework exposes a `CancellationToken` that usually does not get canceled (e.g. `HttpContext.RequestAborted`) they often still need to dispose the backing `CancellationTokenSource` (CTS) after an operation completes rather than reusing it in order to account for callers that might never dispose their registrations.
>
> To use the `RequestAborted` example, Kestrel disposes the backing CTS after every request where the `RequestAborted` token is accessed. If Kestrel attempted to reuse the CTS backing the `RequestAborted` token for future requests in order to reduce allocations, it would risk leaking any undisposed registrations and triggering the undisposed registrations when unrelated requests are aborted.
>
> Another scenario where people want to be able to "reset" a CTS is after calling `CancelAfter()`. This can already be achieved by calling `CancelAfter(Timeout.Infinite)`, but that's not necessarily obvious unless you read the docs. `TryReset()` is something that would immediately make sense in this scenario when looking at intellisense completions.
>
> Another benefit is that it's immediately obvious if resetting failed. If you try resetting a timeout with `CancelAfter()`, you have to check after the call to verify their was no cancellation before or during the call causing `CancelAfter()` to no-op. This is demonstrated in the second `HttpClient` usage example.